# CSV extract issue

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I've recently created a cron to automatize an extract using sqlplus. My .sh is below:

```
alter session set nls_numeric_characters= '.,' ;
alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
set colsep ";"
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET HEADING OFF 
set echo off
SET FEEDBACK OFF
set verify off
set linesize 32767
set pagesize 0
set pause off
set termout off
set newp none
set space 0
set wrap off
set trim on
spool /data/Tools/Extract_W7/w7_errors.csv
Select HOST ||';'|| PORT ||';'|| PID ||';'|| OPX2DATE ||';'|| OPX2USER ||';'|| IP ||';'|| INFO  from V_W7_ERRORS where OPX2DATE > SYSDATE - 100;

spool off;
exit;
```

The problem is that in my extract there is a column "INFO" with specific symbols such as ; / @ # , .. so i think that it confound the colsep used ";" with the ; in the cells.

I tried with different caracters but each time i've the same problem (a lot of rows concatenated in the same cell) because the caracter i use is already used in my Info column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the column contents in double quotes in the CSV, by concatenating those in the query:

```
Select HOST ||';'|| PORT ||';'|| PID ||';'|| OPX2DATE ||';'|| OPX2USER 
  ||';'|| IP ||';"'|| INFO || '"'
from V_W7_ERRORS where OPX2DATE > SYSDATE - 100;
```

The important bit is `';"'|| INFO || '"' which puts a`"` either side of the INFO contents; note that the double-quote mark is itself within the single quotes, so it's output as part of the string, not seen as a quoted identifier.

The output would look like:

```
...;192.168.0.1;"Some info; embedded semicolon is OK now"
```

When you open the file in Excel it won't treat any semicolons within a double-quote-enclosed section as column separators, just as text that is part of the cell value.

You can enclose as many columns as you want in double quotes - any that could possibly have semicolons in. You might want to enclose them all as a precaution.

Comment: My request doesn't contain a double quote after INFO, sorry i made a  pasting mistake.

Comment: My problem is resolved, apparently that was a problem of excel interpretation,i don't have the problem when opening Excel first the Data -Import from text.